# Catan: Cities and Knights: "Using" progress cards to get them out of your hand

Tags: catan, catan-cities-and-knights

Can you "use" a mining card without being adjacent to ore, or an irrigation card without being adjacent to wheat, in order to get them out of your hand and prevent opponents from spying them? You will get 0 cards from them but I'm mainly asking if you can use them up in this case.

Can you "use" a medicine card when you can't actually build a city with it or already have the max 4 cities? Or can you "use" an engineer card when you have no city to place it on or already have the max 3 city walls? Same notion.

I thought the answer was no, as you can't do it online. But I can't find anything in the rules specifically disproving it. Maybe I'm not looking hard enough.

Thanks

Comment: https://www.catan.com/faqs/96?page=6

Answer (score 1):

I agree: the rules don't prohibit you from playing cards simply because it will have no effect. Online or app versions that prevent you from doing so are programmed incorrectly.

As you suggest, there is no specific rule that says this, but following the wording of the specific card should guide you here.

Perhaps the most illustrative examples are **Resource Monopoly** and **Trade Monopoly**. Clearly, if you haven't paid attention, it is easy to choose a resource or commodity that no opponent has in their hand. If so, you don't get to choose something else, you just get zero cards.

Other simple examples:

- **Mining** and **Irrigation**: 2x0 is 0, so you'd collect zero cards.
- **Saboteur**: If you have the most victory points, nobody has to discard cards. (My iPad app gets this one wrong)

Note that the *game state* might prevent you from playing some cards based on the  situation:

- **Master Merchant** starts out: "Select an opponent who has more victory points than you." Maybe I'm reading too much from MTG rules, but my interpretation is that *you cannot play this card* if there are no opponents with more victory points.
- In contrast, **Wedding** says "Each player who has more victory points than you must give you...". If you play the card, and the number of matching players is zero, then you get zero resources, but you're not prevented from playing the card.

Other progress cards are a little less clear:

- Can you play **Crane** but then choose not to buy any city improvements this turn? Probably.
- Can you play **Engineer** if you don't have any city walls (or un-walled cities) available? Not sure, probably not?
- Can you play **Smith** with no knights on the board, or with all knights at max level? Eh... sure?
- Can you play **Smith** with level 1 knights on the board, but *choose not to upgrade any* to level 2? Maybe? Depending on how we interpret "up to two"?

Comment: NOTE: this appears to be incorrect. See [the accepted answer for the linked question](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/39314/608), where an official FAQ says this is not allowed.